# How do I get all the bot acounts in a guild?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm using Heroku now. That's why you see process.env.token3.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot3 = new Discord.Client();


const mark2 = '*info personal'
const mark3 = '*info guild'
bot3.on('message', msg =>{

    if (msg.content.startsWith(mark2)){
        const hashitag = msg.author.id
        const actualhashitag = msg.author.discriminator
        const evenbetterhashitag = "#" + actualhashitag 
        const personalembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Stuff about you')
            .setImage(msg.author.displayAvatarURL())
            .setColor('#D11111')
            .addField('Your username',  msg.author.username)
            .addField('Your hashtag', hashitag, true)
            .addField('Your actual hashtag', actualhashitag, true)
            .addField('Your even realer hashtag', evenbetterhashitag, true)   
            .addField('Your amount of friends', 'Discord bots can not know that sadly')
            .addField('Your role', msg.member.roles.cache.map(role => role.name).join(", ") )
            .addField('Your role id', msg.member.roles.cache.map(role => role.id).join(", ") )
            .addField('Your nickname', msg.member.nickname);
        msg.channel.send(personalembed)
    }
    if (msg.content.startsWith(mark3)){
        let roleID = "720575834771161109";
        const guildembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(msg.guild.name)
            .setImage(msg.guild.iconURL())
            .setColor('#97FF00')
            .addField('the id of the server', msg.guild.id)
            .addField('the owner', msg.guild.owner.user.username)
            .addField('the owner id', msg.guild.ownerID)
            .addField('the owner nickname', msg.guild.owner.nickname)
            .addField('all roles', msg.guild.roles.cache.map(role => role.name).join(", ") ) 
            .addField('the bots', msg.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID).members.map(things => things).join(','))
            .addField('bot 1','Say hello, goodbye and bye in different ways and get different responses')
            .addField('bot 2','Say *interesting with something after it. it will give you a bit of a response')
            .addField('bot 3', 'say *info personal or *info guild to get some imformation. You are using *info guild now')
        msg.channel.send(guildembed)

    }  


})

bot3.login(process.env.token3)
```

This is the script I have now. It works.But I also want to add all the bots in a server to an addField() . I don't know how you get the names of all of the bots in a server though. When I've searched this up I only got how to make a basic discord bot and nothing about this.

Please don't just send a link. Please reply with a full awnser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guild has a property called "members" which is a Collection and contains all the members in the guild. (bots included).
You could do:

```
message.guild.members.cache.map(member => member.user.tag);
```

This creates an array from Collection mapped by your guild member's tags. (Tag#0000)
If you want to include only the bot accounts, you can use [Collection.filter()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) function.

```
message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot)
```

This piece of code will select all of the bots in your guild. Now, what you have to do is to map it by their tag.

```
    message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).map(member => member.user.tag)
```

And then transform it into a string by using the .join() function.

```
    message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).map(member => member.user.tag).join(", ")
   //Result: Dyno#3861, Dank Member#5192 etc...
```

Comment: Makes sense. I'll use this. Good to know